# grammar of 'o so precious'

Tags: idioms, american-english, punctuation

I am writing a essay and in it I use the phrase

> "my o so precious time"

After having a peer review my paper they said that while they didn't know what they felt like there should be a comma or apostrophe after the 'o'.

Is this correct and which should I use?

Comment: I'd use something more formal...

Comment: If you want to use "o so precious", you need either to make capitalize the o ("O so precious") or write "oh so precious".  I don't recommend either; a simple "my precious time" would be preferred--if that's what you want to write.

Comment: The phrase is "oh-so " precious, preferably with the hyphens in place.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry OP seems to have no doubts about the meaning anyway.

Comment: See: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/oh-so

Comment: There are fewer than 40 examples given in a Google search for "my o so precious", and these include: my 'o so precious' towels / my o so precious life / my o' so precious energy / Sharing this with my o! so Precious / my O so precious computer / my o-so-precious Sniper Rifle ammo / MY O-SO PRECIOUS "ANIME" COLLECTIONS.  Searching for "my oh so precious" yields a lot more results (at least one including a comma); I'd say that oh-so-precious and oh so precious, hyphenated and open compound adjectives (without a capital), are about top equal in terms of their use. But informal registers only.

Comment: @Kris For once, I've got to disagree with a respected dictionary. There seem to be extremely few hits (other than in the Oxford dictionaries) for << oh-so ordinary >> and plenty for <<  oh so ordinary >> and <<  oh-so-ordinary >>. I'd say that the doubly hyphenated form is rare after 'be'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Those who follow dictionaries and those that follow the crowd.

Comment: @Kris Most dictionaries claim to follow the crowd (ie their acceptability criteria are based on a descriptive approach). [These (6) Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oh+so+lovely%2Coh-so+lovely%2Coh-so-lovely%2Co+so+lovely%2Co-so+lovely%2Co-so-lovely&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coh%20so%20lovely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coh%20-%20so%20-%20lovely%3B%2Cc0) perhaps indicate that OLD should carry out new surveys.